# Python Slack Bot using asyncio - RuntimeError: Session is closed

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, slack-api

I'm trying to setup the Slack Bot tutorial that uses their RTM framework in python and the WebSocket is not connecting

I'm following this tutorial:

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/tree/master/tutorial#table-of-contents

I follow the code as instructed:

```py
import os
import logging
import slack
import ssl as ssl_lib
import certifi
from onboarding_tutorial import OnboardingTutorial

{"channel": {"user_id": OnboardingTutorial}}


onboarding_tutorials_sent = {}

def start_onboarding(web_client: slack.WebClient, user_id: str, channel: str):
    # Create a new onboarding tutorial.
    onboarding_tutorial = OnboardingTutorial(channel)

    # Get the onboarding message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the onboarding message in Slack
    response = web_client.chat_postMessage(**message)

    # Capture the timestamp of the message we've just posted so
    # we can use it to update the message after a user
    # has completed an onboarding task.
    onboarding_tutorial.timestamp = response["ts"]

    # Store the message sent in onboarding_tutorials_sent
    if channel not in onboarding_tutorials_sent:
        onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel] = {}
    onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel][user_id] = onboarding_tutorial


# ================ Team Join Event =============== #
# When the user first joins a team, the type of the event will be 'team_join'.
# Here we'll link the onboarding_message callback to the 'team_join' event.
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event="team_join")
def onboarding_message(**payload):
    """Create and send an onboarding welcome message to new users. Save the
    time stamp of this message so we can update this message in the future.
    """
    # Get the id of the Slack user associated with the incoming event
    user_id = payload["data"]["user"]["id"]
    # Get WebClient so you can communicate back to Slack.
    web_client = payload["web_client"]

    # Open a DM with the new user.
    response = web_client.im_open(user=user_id)
    channel = response["channel"]["id"]

    # Post the onboarding message.
    start_onboarding(web_client, user_id, channel)


# ============= Reaction Added Events ============= #
# When a users adds an emoji reaction to the onboarding message,
# the type of the event will be 'reaction_added'.
# Here we'll link the update_emoji callback to the 'reaction_added' event.
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event="reaction_added")
def update_emoji(**payload):
    """Update onboarding welcome message after receiving a "reaction_added"
    event from Slack. Update timestamp for welcome message as well.
    """
    data = payload["data"]
    web_client = payload["web_client"]
    channel_id = data["item"]["channel"]
    user_id = data["user"]

    # Get the original tutorial sent.
    onboarding_tutorial = onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel_id][user_id]

    # Mark the reaction task as completed.
    onboarding_tutorial.reaction_task_completed = True

    # Get the new message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the updated message in Slack
    updated_message = web_client.chat_update(**message)

    # Update the timestamp saved on the onboarding tutorial object
    onboarding_tutorial.timestamp = updated_message["ts"]


# =============== Pin Added Events ================ #
# When a users pins a message the type of the event will be 'pin_added'.
# Here we'll link the update_pin callback to the 'reaction_added' event.
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event="pin_added")
def update_pin(**payload):
    """Update onboarding welcome message after receiving a "pin_added"
    event from Slack. Update timestamp for welcome message as well.
    """
    data = payload["data"]
    web_client = payload["web_client"]
    channel_id = data["channel_id"]
    user_id = data["user"]

    # Get the original tutorial sent.
    onboarding_tutorial = onboarding_tutorials_sent[channel_id][user_id]

    # Mark the pin task as completed.
    onboarding_tutorial.pin_task_completed = True

    # Get the new message payload
    message = onboarding_tutorial.get_message_payload()

    # Post the updated message in Slack
    updated_message = web_client.chat_update(**message)

    # Update the timestamp saved on the onboarding tutorial object
    onboarding_tutorial.timestamp = updated_message["ts"]


# ============== Message Events ============= #
# When a user sends a DM, the event type will be 'message'.
# Here we'll link the update_share callback to the 'message' event.
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
def message(**payload):
    """Display the onboarding welcome message after receiving a message
    that contains "start".
    """
    data = payload["data"]
    web_client = payload["web_client"]
    channel_id = data.get("channel")
    user_id = data.get("user")
    text = data.get("text")

    if text and text.lower() == "start":
        return start_onboarding(web_client, user_id, channel_id)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssl_context = ssl_lib.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
    slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
    rtm_client = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token, ssl=ssl_context)
    rtm_client.start()
```

I am getting the following error message - it look like the WebSocket is not connecting for some reason.  I have checked the token to have bot scope, etc.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/badger/.virtualenvs/gcpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slack/rtm/client.py", line 334, in _connect_and_read
    proxy=self.proxy,
  File "/Users/badger/.virtualenvs/gcpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/badger/.virtualenvs/gcpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 728, in _ws_connect
    proxy_headers=proxy_headers)
  File "/Users/badger/.virtualenvs/gcpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 357, in _request
    raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')
RuntimeError: Session is closed
```

Comment: I had the same issue with slackclient 2.3.0. Downgrading to 2.2.1 seems to resolve the issue for now.